# Error C#.NET 3.0: The best overloaded method match for 'CreatePageSection(ref string, ref string, ref object)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#-3.0

I have got the following problem. I encountered an error regarding the default parameters. I added a simple piece of code for an overload. Now I get in the new code (line 3: CreatePageSection(sItemID, "", null);) gives the error mentioned in the title.

I looked for the answer in the other topics, but I can't find the problem. Can someone help me?

The code is found here:

```
public void CreatePageSection(ref string sItemID)
    {
        CreatePageSection(sItemID, "", null);
    }

public void CreatePageSection(ref string sItemID, ref string sFrameUrl, ref object vOnReadyState)
    {

        if (Strings.InStr(msPresentPageSections, "|" + sItemID + "|", 0) > 0) {
            return;
        }
        msPresentPageSections = msPresentPageSections + sItemID + "|";

        string writeHtml = "<div class=" + MConstants.QUOTE + "PageSection" + MConstants.QUOTE + " id=" + MConstants.QUOTE + "Section" + sItemID + "Div" + MConstants.QUOTE + " style=" + MConstants.QUOTE + "display: none;" + MConstants.QUOTE + ">";
        this.WriteLine_Renamed(ref writeHtml);
        //UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object vOnReadyState. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
        //UPGRADE_NOTE: IsMissing() was changed to IsNothing_Renamed(). Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="8AE1CB93-37AB-439A-A4FF-BE3B6760BB23"'
        writeHtml = "  <iframe id=" + MConstants.QUOTE + sItemID + "Frame" + MConstants.QUOTE + " name=" + MConstants.QUOTE + sItemID + "Frame" + MConstants.QUOTE + " frameborder=" + MConstants.QUOTE + "0" + MConstants.QUOTE + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFrameUrl) ? " src=" + MConstants.QUOTE + sFrameUrl + MConstants.QUOTE : "") + ((vOnReadyState == null) ? "" : " onreadystatechange=" + MConstants.QUOTE + Convert.ToString(vOnReadyState) + MConstants.QUOTE) + ">";
        this.WriteLine_Renamed(ref writeHtml);
        writeHtml = "  </iframe>";
        this.WriteLine_Renamed(ref writeHtml);
        writeHtml = "</div>";
        this.WriteLine_Renamed(ref writeHtml);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must pass params by reference

```
public void CreatePageSection(ref string sItemID)
{
    var missingString = String.Empty;
    object missingObject = null;
    CreatePageSection(ref sItemID, ref missingString, ref  missingObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your are not manipulating `sFrameUrl` and `vOnReadyState`, remove the `ref` keyword from those parameters.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.71).aspx